# How can I input a password in Chez Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

I want to write a simple file encryption/decryption program in Chez Scheme, using the scripting feature of Chez Scheme to run the program from the Unix command line. To do that, I need to input the key. I want to prompt the user to enter the key at the keyboard, but with the asterisks echoed to the screen instead of the letters of the key. In other words, an interaction with the program should look like:

```
$ crypt <infile >outfile
Enter key:  ***********
Repeat key: ***********
```

How can I get the terminal into raw mode so it doesn't echo the key as it is typed?

Comment: You need to deal with CFFI to set terminal attributes. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. There's a 60 line implementation in Racket [here](https://github.com/smitchell556/get-pass/blob/master/main.rkt).